# When crafting it always says x random magic effects, is there a way to affect the outcome of this?

Tags: diablo-iii

I've crafted items that give me strength and intelligence which seem like a waste if I'm a monk so should I salvage the item and try again? Is there a way I can influence this so I get items that have magical properties I want?

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to influence the magical properties, random is by definition random.

As far as salvaging items to try again, as you play the game you'll get more and more items that drop. Salvaging the items may not be a bad idea if you're trying to get a certain combination to appear and you may not be able to sell the combination for gold, for example an item that has both strength and intelligence doesn't really benefit any one class very well, but strength and vitality is an awesome one that you cannot use, but a barbarian will. I would salvage the former and try to sell the latter.

Another handy tip is if you have a bit of extra money, the NPCs that sell blues for low prices can be used to get salvage materials for cheap, although just through normal play you will have a lot of blues that drop from champion monsters and bosses.

Comment: Buying blues from NPCs to sell them strikes me as a pretty bad idea. It would probably be cheaper to buy the crafting items from the auction house instead.

Comment: Depends on the market price, and this answer was posted early on in the game's history. At this point, as the market has more of the commodities available the price will drop. And I did preface it by saying if they had extra money (which most won't).

Answer (score 1):

Salvaging a crafted item seems like a waste of resources.  You are probably better off trying to recoup some of those costs through the gold auction house where it may be useful to another player.